# How can I tell when a collection has been edited?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I have a public property called Items, It's a List. I want to tell when it's been altered. How can I do this?

For example, if Items.Add is called, I want to be able to then call UpdateInnerList.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you use the `ObservableCollection`?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

Comment: My only caveat about using `ObservableCollection` is that if you need to action the items that are changing, the `.Clear()` method raises the changed event but has no items in the arguments, thus, you do not know what was removed. This is obviously only relevant if you care.

Comment: Version Info from the link:  Supported in: 4, 3.5, 3.0

Comment: @Mark, in the case of Clear() I would suspect that a Reset would be the action in the CollectionChanged event.  In other cases like Add, Remove I think that there are members on the NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs that can be used?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs.action.aspx

Comment: Yes, ObservableCollection is only available 3.5 or higher, but the question is tagged for .Net 3.5.

Comment: @Wil P, I wish.  When you call `.Clear()`, the event is raised (as you say of type Reset) and both `NewItems` and `OldItems` are null.  I believe the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` actually throw if you attempt to circumvent that behavior.

Comment: @Wil P, just reread your comment, yes, the items affected are present for all events on the event arguments _except_ the Reset.  This is important to those that wish to action those items there were cleared away.

Comment: Could you provide a code sample? I'm having difficulty getting this to work. Are you sure this will work for WinForms? My research shows this is part of the WPF

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a List subclass and overriding the Add method?

```
void Main()
{
    var x=new MySpecialList<string>();
    x.Add("hello");
}

class MySpecialList<T>:List<T>
{
    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        //special action here
        Console.WriteLine("added "+item);
        base.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: And if it's stuffed into the base `List<T>` as a variable, this `.Add` will never be called.

Comment: "stuffed into the base..."? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: `List<int> items = new MySpecialList<int>();  items.Add(5);`  There is no console output written.  It's the bane of using `new` to shadow the base class's method instead of, for example, implementing `IList<T>` instead of what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

Try [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)

It supports a [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) event which should be what you need.